# Is there a way to tell what verbs are more efficient

Tags: performance, optimization, cobol

Aside from just running strobes, or checking CPU usage at the end of a job, is there anyway for me to find out which COBOL verbs are more CPU intensive? Take this example:

Would it be more efficient to use this inspect statement (assume VARA is a PIC X(10) )

```
INSPECT VARA REPLACING ALL SPACE 
                       BY  HIGH-VALUE
```

or would it be better to write a loop

```
PERFORM VARYING SUB1
        FROM    1 BY 1
        UNTIL   SUB1 > 10
   IF VARA(SUB1:1) = SPACE
      MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO VARA(SUB1:1)
   END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

**BACKGROUND**

I have some programs that are handling files with millions of records and some of the jobs are not performing as well as we would like. I am trying to analyze the long running jobs and find non-invasive way to speed them up (like the above example of changing an inspect for a loop). The only problem is, I don't actually know what is actually more efficient. We don't want to do change for change sake, but if I could somehow tell that a change would improve performance, we would almost certainly do it.

I am using Z/OS 2.01.00 and COBOL for Z/OS 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make the question too broad to deal with everything, so sticking to `INSPECT` and your `PERFORM` example.

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  THE-STRING                          PIC X(50). 
   01  A-HIGH-VALUE                        PIC X VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
   01  A-SPACE                             PIC X VALUE SPACE. 

   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       INSPECT THE-STRING 
         REPLACING                  ALL SPACE 
                                    BY HIGH-VALUE 
       INSPECT THE-STRING 
         CONVERTING                 ' ' 
                                    TO X'FF' 
       INSPECT THE-STRING 
         CONVERTING                 HIGH-VALUE 
                                    TO HIGH-VALUE 
       INSPECT THE-STRING 
         REPLACING                  ALL A-HIGH-VALUE 
                                    BY A-HIGH-VALUE 
       INSPECT THE-STRING 
         CONVERTING                 A-HIGH-VALUE 
                                    TO A-HIGH-VALUE 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

INSPECT has multiple formats. The above includes two of the formats, and uses literals, figurative-constants and data-names. All the INSPECTs produce the same result. The generated code...

```
000010  INSPECT                                                                                                  
   000544  DC31 8000 A12C          TR    0(50,8),300(10)         THE-STRING                        PGMLIT AT +292

000011  INSPECT                                                                                                  
   00054A  DC31 8000 A12C          TR    0(50,8),300(10)         THE-STRING                        PGMLIT AT +292

000012  INSPECT                                                                                                  
   000550  DC31 8000 A12C          TR    0(50,8),300(10)         THE-STRING                        PGMLIT AT +292

000013  INSPECT                                                                                                  
   000556  D2FF D100 A02C          MVC   256(256,13),44(10)      TS2=0                             PGMLIT AT +36 
   00055C  41E0 D100               LA    14,256(0,13)            TS2=0                                           
   000560  1BFF                    SR    15,15                                                                   
   000562  BFF1 8038               ICM   15,1,56(8)              A-HIGH-VALUE                                    
   000566  1AFE                    AR    15,14                                                                   
   000568  D200 F000 8040          MVC   0(1,15),64(8)           A-SPACE                                         
   00056E  DC31 8000 D100          TR    0(50,8),256(13)         THE-STRING                        TS2=0         

000014  INSPECT                                                                                                  
   000574  5820 905C               L     2,92(0,9)               TGTFIXD+92                                      
   000578  58F0 2044               L     15,68(0,2)              V(IGZCIN1 )                                     
   00057C  4110 A296               LA    1,662(0,10)             PGMLIT AT +654                                  
   000580  0DEF                    BASR  14,15
```

As can be seen, the first three examples (where the compiler knows the values to be changed and what they are to be changed to) all produce a simple TR, Translate, instruction which will absolutely tear the face off anything you can code in COBOL, as far as performance is concerned.

The fourth does some work (each time) to set up for the TR. The fifth establishes parameters to a run-time routine (IGZCIN1) and then lets that rip.

All of these will beat your loop. More so as the size of the field extends.

Of course, if your field is short, you have a chance for a win using simple IFs.

TR is fast, but does require a 256-byte translate table.

Mostly INSPECT is very rapid, and, as with all verbs, intrinsically knows the lengths of everything, so no chance of an "off-bye-one" of coding your own.

Some sites, stupidly, "ban" the use of INSPECT through faulty thinking (or, simply put, no thinking). TALLYING for ALL CHARACTERS can be considered slow, but why ever use that?

Now, to your PERFORM. If you want to be efficient whilst looping through something to look at every byte, don't do it like that :-)

```
PERFORM VARYING SUB1
        FROM    1 BY 1
        UNTIL   SUB1 > 10
   IF VARA(SUB1:1) = SPACE
      MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO VARA(SUB1:1)
   END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

You have "VARYING", but what varies? You are looking at 10 bytes. Nothing variable there. Oh, of course, it looks more like "code" (from some other language) and saves you loads of typing. At a cost, paid daily :-)

```
MOVE ZERO TO SUB1
PERFORM LENGTH OF VARA TIMES
   ADD 1 TO SUB1 
   IF VARA ( SUB1 : 1 ) = SPACE
      MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO VARA ( SUB1 : 1 )
   END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

(I haven't done the full formatting, because VARA is there, and the reference-modification...)

And then, let's say you have to test for something longer than one byte, and decide to use OCCURS with an INDEXED BY because it is "more efficient". Yet, using literals, and even with LENGTH OF, interest yourself with the tortuous code produced. This is because the compiler has to "normalise" an index when comparing it to a literal, it has to turn it from a displacement into an entry-number for the comparison. What you gain by using INDEXED BY you loose (perhaps all of, or more, even) by being slack and using VARYING.

To get a more general feel for more than just a couple of types of a couple of the formats of INSPECT, you need to generate the "pseudo assembler", understand what it is doing (at least in general terms) and then run some stub-programs and actually compare the resources consumed, and type to convince yourself of where any differences are consumed.

It won't all come at once, it is an ongoing process, and then, when you get to Enterprise COBOL V5+, it starts over again, because everything is changed :-)

Answer (score 3):

Where possible and feasible, we would use our shop's vendor utilities instead of writing COBOL.  SORT utilities, for example, are often highly optimized for I/O and perform very well.

There *may* be a trade off between maintainability and efficiency.  It has been argued that COBOL is easier to understand and debug than SORT control cards.  I think that depends on the nature of the task to be accomplished.

My decision tree was:

1. Attempt to accomplish the goal with vendor utilities
2. If that cannot reasonably be done then attempt to accomplish the goal with custom
   code using existing generic subroutines
3. Write custom code, attempting to create generic subroutines which
   can be used in similar future circumstances

For "reasonably" in #2, one coworker would give up on vendor utilities when he hit 3 job steps.  My limit was higher.  Your own rule of diminishing returns will depend on many factors.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler highly optimizes things, so a good starting point would be to make sure all of that is turned on.  Since you mention Strobe, I'll assume you have it available.  It will give you reports of which sections of code are taking up the bulk of your time, and usually, it's not where you expect it to be, so I would say run those reports and see which verbs are causing you issues and try other approaches to accomplish the same things.

In the case above, the INSPECT statement should turn into a very fast TR instruction.  But the compiler might be able to optimize the heck out of that PERFORM loop by unrolling it and turning it into a very fast series of CLI/MVI statements, or perhaps even the same TR instruction.

Most likely, neither of those is going to be your problem.  You might also look at the files you are processing and make sure they are properly blocked and buffered and all that, usually you can get some good bank for your tuning buck there.